# 'HitCountDetailView' object has no attribute 'category'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to add extra context which does filtering to my DetailView. It throws the error that the view object has no attribute category

**model**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=True)
```

**view.py**

````py
class HitCountDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    slug_field = 'slug'
    count_hit = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['similar_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(category=self.category).exclude(slug=self.slug)
        return context


**urls.py**


```python
    path('detail/<slug>/', HitCountDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail')
````

Answer (score 1):

You should filter with `self.object.category`, not <s>`self.category`</s>, and `self.object.slug`, not <s>`self.slug`</s>. You thus can implement this with:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['similar_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(
        category=self.object.category
    ).exclude(pk=self.object.pk)
    return context
```

You can optimize the efficiency by querying with the object itself, not with its category:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['similar_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(
        category__post=self.object
    ).exclude(pk=self.object.pk)
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad you've helped